# Create Cross-Platform Application (Android, iOS) as an option to open PDF documents

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

#### Hello,

I've developed an *Android* application in Java for creating electronic signatures upon **PDF** documents. To run the application, the user should choose a PDF document from stored documents and after the *Open With picker* prompts, the user should choose the developed application and the application starts. In *Java* I managed to do that by setting an intent-filter (with mimetype set for application/pdf) in the Antroid Manifest file of the project. I want to do the same thing in a **Xamarin.Forms** cross-platform application. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible through official Xamarin.Essentials:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/essentials/launcher?context=xamarin%2Fxamarin-forms&tabs=android

> This features enables an app to request other apps to open and view a
>   file. Xamarin.Essentials will automatically detect the file type
>   (MIME) and request the file to be opened.

Here is a sample of writing text to disk and requesting it be opened:

```
var fn = "File.txt";
var file = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, fn);
File.WriteAllText(file, "Hello World");

await Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
{
    File = new ReadOnlyFile(file)
});
```

Comment: will this method comply with new storage policy in play store?

Comment: @D.madushanka sure it will work.